# Foreign key is not working (asp.net & SQL Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

1. I created the foreign key between child and parent. `Parentid` on `parent` table is set to auto-increment. In UI, when I done with creating parent, it redirects me to create child. The problem is after I create the child, I open the data in child table, the foreign key (`parentid`) is NULL, it doesn't inherit the `parentid` from parent table. Why is this so?
2. I logged in as admin and create user parent and child. Let's say, after a while, I wanted to add a child to an existing parent. How am I going to do that ?

[image: database tables]

Comment: When creating the child row (typically with an SQL `insert` command) it's up to you to provide the parent id.

Comment: ok but without a parent id in child row, how am i going to know which child belongs to which parent ?

Comment: The child row doesn't automatically "inherit" the foreign key value - you need to **set it** to a correct value that's present in the parent table

Comment: ok. I do it the first time but do i have to keep on updating the value each time new child is created ?

Comment: When you insert a child row, yes, you have to set a value for the foreign key